# Sorting two List (String, Integer) in java based on Integer value

Tags: java, list

I am working on a program where i am reading a file and extracting keywords and their count. Later i need to pick up word with topmost frequency and match them with a keyword.

I have stored all the keywords i have found in the file in String list. 
I wish to sort these on basis of frequency. So if at index 17 i have a word "stack" with value at index 17 in other integer list to be maximum, i wish to take them to position 1.

I can sort these using collections.sort but it does not take care of other list.

Here is my code :

```
while(m.find()) 
    {
        if(keyword.contains(m.group()))
            {
            keywordcount.set(keyword.indexOf(m.group()),keywordcount.get(keyword.indexOf(m.group()))+1);
            //System.out.println("*"+m.group()+":"+keywordcount.get(keyword.indexOf(m.group())));
            }
        else
            {
            keyword.add(m.group());
            int var=keyword.indexOf(m.group());
            //System.out.println(m.group()+":"+var);
            keywordcount.add(var, 1);
            }
        //System.out.println(keyword.size()+"#"+keywordcount.size());                       
    }
    for(int i=0;i<keyword.size();i++)
    {
        System.out.print(keyword.get(i)+ ":" +keywordcount.get(i)+" ");
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically, one would put both the `String` and the `Integer` into a single class, and sort a list of instances of that class.

E.g.

```
class StringCount implements Comparable<StringCount> {
    private final String string;
    private final int count;

    public StringCount(String string, int count) {
        this.string = string;
        this.count = count;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(StringCount right) {
        return this.count < right.count ? -1
             : this.count > right.count ? 1
             : 0;
    }

    // implement equals and hashCode too
    // if a.compareTo(b) == 0, then a.equals(b) should return true.

}
```

Then, you can create a `List<StringCount>` and call `Collections.sort(stringCountList)`.

Note, that this will put the `StringCount` instances with the **lowest** values first, so they come out in ascending order.

Comment: The compareTo method's body can be reduced to `return count - right.count;`

Comment: No, that might overflow.  -2 billion - 2 billion for example

Answer (score 1):

```
final List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
final Map<String, Integer> frequencies = new HashMap<>();

while (m.find())  {
    String word = ...extract the word from m...;

    if (!words.contains(word)) words.add(word);

    if (!frequencies.contains(word)) frequencies.put(word, 1);
    else frequencies.put(word, frequencies.get(word) + 1);
}

Collections.sort(words, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        int f1 = frequencies.get(s1);
        int f2 = frequencies.get(s2);
        if (f1 < f2) return 1;
        if (f1 > f2) return -1;
        return 0;
    }
});
```

Comment: i was using hashmaps earlier.. but did the sort u suggesting keeps the unique elements ?

Comment: This implementation will probably fit your use case better - however, I would suggest using MutableInt from apache commons lang, because this will avoid a lot of boxing & unboxing in the counting - because you can increment the count rather than putting a new value in for the count.

Comment: What do you mean by "the unique elements"? Every time a keyword is found, it is saved in the list if not already present, and its frequency is increased. Finally, the list is sorted in reverse order based on the frequencies. The list "words" will only contains unique keywords, and will be sorted based on their frequency, in descending order.

Comment: By the way, I agree with @daveb. If you don't want to use the whole apache commons lang library for this, just quickly create a MutableInt class, it's trivial for this use case.

Comment: @AurélienRibon i tried using your code... i think if (f1<f2) i need to swap the list ? because my code is giving me almost same results even now

Comment: Swap the list? With what? I don't really understand what you want to do and what is the issue I admit.

Comment: @AurélienRibon i implemented your code.. now i am printing my hashmap.. it is still not sorted..

Comment: A HashMap is never sorted! The sorted list is the "words" objects, not the "frequencies" one. Look what parameter is passed to Collections.sort(), it's "words"...

Comment: oh.. then it defeats my purpose.. i am looking for something else..i.e. a list of all words in their decreasing frequencies thank you anyways for sharing your suggestions.

Comment: And that's exactly what is the "words" list at the end of my code: a list of all words sorted by decreasing frequencies. The hashmap "frequencies" is just an intermediate object to sort the list.

Answer (score 1):

This might be the ideal moment to check into [multisets](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html).

> A collection that supports order-independent equality, like Set, but may have duplicate elements. A multiset is also sometimes called a bag.
>
> Elements of a multiset that are equal to one another are referred to as occurrences of the same single element. The total number of occurrences of an element in a multiset is called the count of that element (the terms "frequency" and "multiplicity" are equivalent, but not used in this API). Since the count of an element is represented as an int, a multiset may never contain more than Integer.MAX_VALUE occurrences of any one element.